# Why drag and drop not working

Tags: qt, qml

This is the basic example I found on [qt doc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-draganddrop-example.html). In `tile` Rectangle, i add `anchors.fill: parent` and commented all 3 lines below that because I feel like all those 3 line can be covered by `anchors.fill: parent`. But once I do that I cannot drag the element anymore.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true


    Item {
        id: root

        width: 64; height: 64

        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea

            anchors.fill: parent
            anchors.centerIn: parent

            drag.target: tile

            onReleased: parent = tile.Drag.target !== null ? tile.Drag.target : root

            Rectangle {
                id: tile

                anchors.fill: parent
//                width: 64; height: 64
//                anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
//                anchors.horizontalCenter: parent.horizontalCenter


                color: "red"

                Drag.active: mouseArea.drag.active
                Drag.hotSpot.x: 32
                Drag.hotSpot.y: 32
                states: State {
                    when: mouseArea.drag.active
                    ParentChange { target: tile; parent: root }
                    AnchorChanges { target: tile; anchors.verticalCenter: undefined; anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined }
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Why filling the rectangle of the parent disables the drag and drop functionality?

Answer (score 0):

You anchor a boat so that it is fixed at something. If you want to move it, you will need to break the anchor or pull the thing you anchored it to, with you.

That is what an anchor is for - to fix the anchored object to some other object. If you want to have it movable, you can't anchor it.

You still have the dragged object *the same size* as your parent, by setting:

```
width: parent.width
height: parent.height
```

But though it is the same size, once you move it, it will obviously *not fill* the parent anymore.

Now you might say:
*"But hey! They do anchor the object, too!"*

Yes, they do, but there are also the lines:

```
states: State {
    when: mouseArea.drag.active
    ParentChange { target: tile; parent: root }
    AnchorChanges { target: tile; anchors.verticalCenter: undefined; anchors.horizontalCenter: undefined }
}
```

which will *lift the anchor* when the tile is being dragged.